# Speed-up vector summation

Tags: matlab, performance, while-loop, sum

I have this conceptual algorithm in Matlab to sum the elements of a vector `x` in a while loop:

```
while y <= ythreshold

y = sum(x(x <= xthreshold));

end
```

Suppose we add an additional condition that the size of the `x` vector is growing during this loop. Obviously, what we can expect is that the summation operation should take more time as the size of the `x` vector will increase. I want to ask which measures we can take to increase the speed of the summation.

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be in?  Edit to include the correct tag, at least?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I made the necessary changes.

Comment: Is `x` a column vector? Because your code is not summing the columns of a matrix. If you already have the sum and add elements, why would you re-sum all of those previous elements rather than just summing the new elements and adding that to the total sum? Please provide an example of what you're trying to do with sample input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: x is a column vector. Basically what I did was to divide a number by two random fractions successively as long as the summation of the divided values (x) below a threshold value (xthreshold) exceeded another threshold (ythreshold). By the way, thank you for the suggestion. The revised code worked quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cumsum` to calculate the cumulative sum of a vector:

```
ySum = cumsum(x);
% logical check
lg = ySum < ythreshold;
% get last index
idx = find(lg,'last');
y = ySum(idx);
```

The speed advantage depends on how large is `x` and how far ahead you find the value.

PS: In general, it would help a lot, if you provide a minimum valuable example (MVE), so people can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Basically what I did was to divide a number by two random fractions successively as long as the summation of the divided values (x) below a threshold value (xthreshold) exceeded another threshold (ythreshold).

Comment: that sounds like you need the infinite-loop. If you want to speed that up, you can compile the code as a mex-function